rational homology of SO(2,1) over number fields
Let $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$ be the special orthogonal group defined by the quadratic from $q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$.
This is a connected non-simpy connected algebraic group.
Now, let $F$ be a number field, and let $G=\mathrm{SO}(2,1)(F)$ be the (abstract) group of $F$-points of $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$.
My question is the following: What is known on the rational homology groups $H_*(G,\mathbb{Q})?$ Is it true that $H_p(G,\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p>>0$?
In a geometric case, i.e., assuming that $F=\mathbb{C}$, Is there an integer $N>0$ such that $H_p(G,\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p>N$? Is $N=3$?
In the article entitled "the homology of $\mathrm{SL}_2(F[t,t^{-1}])$", K. P. Knudson proves that $H_p(\mathrm{SL}_2(F),\mathbb{Q})=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, for all $p \geq 2r+3s+1$, where $r$ (resp. $s$) is the number of real (resp. conjugate pairs of complex) embeddings of $F$.
In order to prove this fact, Knudson uses a result due to Borel and Yang (see the article "The rank conjecture for number fields") on the rational cohomology of $\mathrm{SL}_2(F)$. However, the Borel & Yang's result holds for simply connected groups (thus it does not directly apply for $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$).
We can work with the $\mathrm{Spin}(2,1)$ group, but I think that there are some technical difficulties.
Thanks in advance :)

Isn’t $\text{SO}(2,1)(F)$ the same as $\text{PSL}_2(F)$? In this case the rational cohomology should be the same as for $\text{SL}_2(F)$.

Dear Kasper: When $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$, I agree with the your claim. In these cases, we have that $\mathrm{SO}(2,1) \cong \mathrm{PSL}2(F)$. In any other cases, I dont know. However, it is possible that, we can attack the problem by using the quadratic form defined by split quaternions (i.e., in the $\mathbb{M}{2\times2}$ case). I dont know the details. Do you have a reference where is proved that $\mathrm{SO}(2,1) \cong \mathrm{PSL}_2(F)$ over any number field F? Thanks in advace :)

I don't have a reference, but the same argument as for $\mathbb{R}$ should work: Let $F$ be any field of characteristic $0$. Then $G=\text{SL}_2(F)$ acts on $V=F^2$. The action of $G$ on the symmetric square $S^2(V)$ gives a homomorphism $G\rightarrow \text{SL}_3(F)$ with kernel ${\pm 1}$, and choosing the right basis, the image preserves the quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$. This gives the desired isomorphism $\text{PSL}_2(F) \stackrel{\cong}{\longrightarrow} \text{SO}(2,1)(F)$.
